# Deleting Isolated subgraph in a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have a graph 
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4, 5->6}]
Now I want to identify the vertices of a subgraph which are isolated from the main graph.(In this case subgraph 5->6 since they are not connected to bigger graph).
I have a similar case where there is a huge interconnected graph and there are several subgraphs which have 4-5 vertexes and not a part of big graph.

So I want to identify the vertices of these smaller graphs

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "isolated vertex". The usual definition is a zero-degree vertex, of which there aren't any here.

Comment: You've seen `ConnectedComponents[]`?

Comment: ... [WeaklyConnectedComponents](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/WeaklyConnectedComponents.html)?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, you can use `Graph` and the first (largest) element of `WeaklyConnectedComponents`:

```
g1 = Graph[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1, 3 -> 2, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 4, 
   5 -> 6}, VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
wcc = WeaklyConnectedComponents[g1]
```

> {{4, 1, 2, 3}, {5, 6}}

```
Subgraph[g1, wcc[[1]], VertexShapeFunction -> "Name"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]